# How is possible that X is acting like a vector and a concrete variable at the same time (R)?

Tags: r, recursion

I'll use the following code example:

```
minmax_norm <- function(X) {
  (X - min(X))/diff(range(X))
}

dSeeds_minmax <- apply(dSeeds,2,minmax_norm)
```

How is possible that X is acting like each column of the dataframe and also is acting as each variable of the column? I mean min(X) is the minimum value of the column but X - min(X) is the current value of the variable minus the minimum value of all the column.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: R tends to do things on a whole vector at a time. `apply` is going to cal the `minmax_norm` function for each column (second argument `2`), so `X` will be the whole column, which is a vector. In many/most programming languages, you need a `for` loop to do the same function on each value in an array, but in R it is typically more efficient to operate on the vector once (R does the `for` loop internally). C.f. `(1+3) + 1` is a vector operation. So when `X` is a vector of numbers, `X-min(X)` shifts them (same length) and `diff(range(X))` finds the spread (length 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost always dealing with vectors in R. Even:

```
x <- 1
```

x here is just a vector of length 1. If R encounters a vector operation on two vectors of different lengths, like:

```
X - min(X)
```

It checks to see if the length of the smaller vector is a factor of the length of the larger vector. If it is, R assumes you wanted the smaller vector repeated in order to do the operation.